# Rank of matrix ABC

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose we are given three real matrices $A$,$B$,$C$ of sizes $40 × 20, 20×30, 30×40$. And the rank of the matrix $AB$, $BC$, $C$ are $11,12,15$ respectively.
Then how should I find minimum possible rank of matrix $ABC$?

I tried using formula
$rank(AB) \leq min(rank(A),rank(B))$

As given $rank(B)=15$ and $rank(BC)=12$
$\implies rank(BC)\leq (rank(B),15)$
$\implies rank(B) = 12$

Similarly, $rank(A) = 11$

Now I stuck how to find minimum $rank(ABC)$ because the formula gives the maximum possible rank!

Comment: To minimize the rank try to maximize the dimension of the nullspace.

Comment: I suggest trying first with (nonsquare) diagonal matrices with only 1 or 0 on the diagonal.

Comment: $\text{rank}(BC)\le \min(\text{rank}(B),15)$ does not imply $\text{rank}(B)=12$; it only implies that $12\le \text{rank}(B)$.

Comment: @Ak9848 $rank(B)$ is $15$ or $rank(C)$ is $15$. As you write "As given $rank(B) = 15$". Clearify this.

Comment: @Ak9848 it can be solved  if rank of matrix $B$ is given instead of matrix $C$ rank.